# Confusion over xml.startElement() parameter in java

Tags: java, xml

I came across some xml parsers in some code in Java, I don't know what the first parameter in the following line represent ?

```
this.xml.startElement("", "", "root", atts);
```

I can see that it represents Namespace URI, but what does it mean when using "", "" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's stated in the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29).  The parameters are:

1. `uri` - the Namespace URI, or **the empty string if the element has no Namespace URI or if Namespace processing is not being performed**
2. `localName` - the local name (without prefix), or **the empty string if Namespace processing is not being performed**
3. `qName` - the qualified name (with prefix), or the empty string if qualified names are not available
4. `atts` - the attributes attached to the element. If there are no attributes, it shall be an empty Attributes object. The value of this object after startElement returns is undefined